# Closing all child windows

Tags: javascript

The web site could spawn one or more pop up windows.

When the main browser window is closed, i would like all the child windows to be closed as well.

Currently, I am performing this

```
  $(window).on('unload', function () {
  if (_chatWindow && !_chatWindow.closed)
  {
    _chatWindow.close();
  };
  if (_wazeWindow && !_wazeWindow.closed)
  {
    _wazeWindow.close();
  };
  if (_mapWindow && !_mapWindow.closed)
  {
    _mapWindow.close();
  };
  });
```

This seems to work if each child window is opened, but if, for example the _chatWindow is not opened, the _wazeWindow and _mapWindow windows are not being closed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to ensure all the child popup windows can be closed when the parent window is closed.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? Personally I would generalize this, maintain an array of windows instead and then do `childWindows.forEach(w => !w.closed && w.close())`.

Comment: `const childWindows = [_chatWindow, _wazeWindow, _mapWindow]; childWindows.forEach(w => w && !w.closed && w.close && w.close())`

Comment: I've used the array technique as  suggested by @FelixKling. It worked in the past and it's working right now. What browser are you using and could you provide a code snippet that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: Great ideas!!!    i went with justin chase comment.    please provide it as an answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the idea that felix and justin presented.